# How to use Luis Intent in Botbuilder v4 framework without downloading the json file from LUIS

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using the below code :

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/csharp_dotnetcore/

I have loaded csharp_dotnetcore.sln in visual studio file and able to see core-bot todo-bot ,using-cards and multi-turn-prompt . I am able to build the project.
It is mentioned in README that I have to download the json file from LUIS and put in specific location.However, even after downloading the file and putting in the location, intents are not getting recognized.

Please help me with adding a LUIS intent in this project.

And also where to do the necessary changes to identify the intents provided in chat bot. Will it be in RootDialog.cs ?
I have also put the LUIS app id and key and hostname in CoreBot.luis.json.

In the attached screenshot ,sample output can be seen. Where it is only producing the output from CoreBot.luis.json file and its kind of a static output, even though after changing the  json file content i am getting the same response in chatbot and i also want it to detect the output directly from LUIS portal

[image: I have already trained and published the intents in LUIS.]

Please help.

Comment: If you have a LUIS app deployed, you shouldn't need a .lu file. Can you share your code where you are calling LUIS/recognizing the intent?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/csharp_dotnetcore   in this i am using using-cards project and  after building, in chatbot emulator i am  testing .

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to add LUIS to the cards bot?

Comment: I have loaded csharp_dotnetcore.sln in visual studio and when i am trying to build it ,using debugger i can see todo-bot's  RootDialog.cs  is invoked and its using a luis file ToDoLuisBot.luis.json (can be searched in project easily) ,so i dont want to use this file instead i want to connect to LUIS directly using App id and Key which is set in appsettings.json . This code might contain the logic to connect to luis , i am also searching that logic. If  LUIS can be added to cards bot or todo bot anything is fine for me.

Comment: @billoverton i am also trying to search that part of code where it tries to call Luis app using app id and key. Using debugger code flow starts from  RootDialog.cs of todo-bot . In the beginning import csharp_dotnetcore.sln to visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your issue here is sheer confusion. You list 3 separate projects that you're saying aren't working.

Both the CoreBot and the ToDoBot require LUIS. You have to add the LUIS model on your LUIS.ai portal using either the CLI or manually through the portal upload:

[image: howtoaddluis]

Once you have your LUIS app created, you can use the appID and Password you get from the LUIS portal to add to the appsettings.json file:

[image: portal Key]

[image: appsettings.json]

In the question, you say you're using CoreBot, in the first comment, you say you're using Cards Bot, and in a later comment you say you're using ToDo Bot. Those are three different bots in the solution, so you're probably putting your keys in the wrong appsetttings.json file. Double check that you're using the right appsettings.json file.

Also to note: the bots in the experimental branch are meant to see different possible approaches that the Bot Framework might take going forward, and should not be used in production environments. They are not guaranteed to work, and are not supported.

Comment: Hi @JJ_Wailes . I have already LUIS app registered and using test environment . Also ,i have made entry in appsetting json file and MicroSoftAppId and password is left blank.  .TodoBotwithLUIS card and then in chatbot emulator it always shows me static card and response configured in ToDoLuisBot json file  . Again, i changed the ToDoLuisBot  with my intents in LUIS (export json to local folder) and replaced ToDoLuisBot  file . But its taking the input from RootDialog.lu file always . So , how can i make this code make use of LUIS app id and key and connect to LUIS and using  intents.

Comment: Now,i am only specific to  building core-bot ,whe i build it and test in bot emulator i get some static cards and hen i enter my intents in json file ,chatbot gives no response.  . UpdateModel.bat file has commands to process intent from json file and luis. But,i am not sure ,how it works.